# Encrypt a textfile with gnupg on the console

Tags: gnupg

It is easy to decrypt an encrypted textfile with:

```
 gpg --decrypt /tmp/message
```

But how can I encrypt my own textfile?

Comment: http://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x110.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encrypting is as easy as decrypting:

```
gpg --encrypt /tmp/message
```

GnuPG will now ask you for the key(s) to encrypt to. The encrypted message will be stored to the same path with `.gpg` extension. The output file can be set using `--output /path/to/encrypted/file`.

You can also include the recipient as parameter, useful for scripting gpg, add `--recipient foo@example.org`.

For more options, read `man gpg` and the [GnuPG manual](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/).